# Pandas giving me an import error for Datautil?

Tags: pandas, pip

I am trying to import the pandas module. However, when attempting to run my code, I get the following error:

```
    raise ImportError('dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version')
ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version
```

However, I already have the 2.5.0 verison on my computer, as seen from the following message when attempting to pip install.

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Users/nat/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (2.5.0)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you import `pandas` in the same Python 3.5 for which `dateutil` is installed? It could be a different Python version and it couldn't import packages installed for this Python.

Comment: can you please provide full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing below package,

```
pip install python-dateutil==2.5.0
```